# Duplicate values on join

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to create a table using the following query:

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE AS
        SELECT A.* ,B.FIELD_1, B.FIELD_2
            FROM TEST AS A
                LEFT JOIN OTHER_TABLE AS B ON A.CONTRACT = B.CONTRACT
                    AND (A.CUSTOMER = B.CUSTOMER OR A.CUSTOMER_NEW = B.CUSTOMER);
QUIT;
```

but that query returns duplicate values. I am guessing that the `OR` i am using on the join is causing that because in some cases it will match one of the conditions or both. Also i am removing duplicates on `OTHER_TABLE` before i do the join.
How can i make it match `A.CUSTOMER = B.CUSTOMER` and then `A.CUSTOMER_NEW = B.CUSTOMER` only if it didn't find a match for the first one? I am using left join because i want to keep all the records in `TEST` and get null values when it does not find anything even after checking those conditions.

Comment: Can you join like this: left join coalesce(a.customer, a.customer_new) = b.customer. Not sure that will fix your duplicate problem, but a place to start.

Comment: Simply `SELECT DISTINCT`? Otherwise a [mcve] is needed.

Comment: So some observation in TEST is matching two different CUSTOMERs in OTHER_TABLE.  What do you want to do in that case?  Do you want to take the values that match CUSTOMER or CUSTOMER_NEW?

Comment: @Tom I would like to keep the ones that match CUSTOMER.

Comment: "Returns duplicate values"  So does test have the same contract for the same customer listed multiple times?  how about "Other_table" If either have multiples of those you'll get multiples in your results due to the X:M relationship.  prove it `Select count(*) from Test group by customer, contract having count(*) > 1 ` if you get more than one you have a problem.  Change this to "other_Table" and try again as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try two left joins.

```
proc sql;
create table new_table as
  select a.*
       , case when (missing(b.customer)) then c.field_1 else b.field_1 as field_1
       , case when (missing(b.customer)) then c.field_2 else b.field_2 as field_2
from test as a
left join other_table as b
  on a.customer = b.customer and a.contract = b.contract
left join other_table as c
  on a.customer_new = c.customer and a.contract = c.contract
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

you use *left join* , make sure all fields are not the same, maybe one field are different

Comment: Thanks participating in this question. You should leave your feedback as a comment instead of answer.